# How to Generate unit tests in visual studio 2015,x64 configuration

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, msdn

I have gone through msdn articles for generating the unit  tests in visual studio.I got known that **IntelliTest** does not support x64 configuration.and I have tried using **rightClick**=>**Create Unit tests**=>Selecting test framework **MSTest** and **xUnit.Net 2.0** i have generated unit test case but it is generating with empty method unit test case.

I am not able to get **Run IntelliTes**t or **Smart Unit Tests** option in Context menu to generate unit test cases.[By right clicking i am getting context menu like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFrBy.png.)
Is there any way to generate unit test cases in visual studio 2015,x64 Configuration..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! this is not supported yet.
Kindly consider voting for it on uservoice here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/10139661-enable-intellitest-for-64-bit-projects